# nth child using formula

Tags: html, css

hello i have like 6 thumbail who have same class for each thumbnails.
i want the 2nd,5th to have `margin-left:36px;` and the 3nd and 6th to have `83px`.

so i write css like this

```
.commitee-members{
  margin:10px 15px;
}
.commitee-members-outers:nth-child(3n+2) .commitee-members{
    margin-left: 36px;
}
.commitee-members-outers:nth-child(3n+3) .commitee-members{
    margin-left: 83px;
}
```

i dont know why, but the 5th class got `margin-left:83px` and he 6th class didnt have `margin-left:83px`.
so i check with some exercise but this time its work
heres my case

https://jsfiddle.net/bheoqL9e/1/

as you can see, its messed up

but on this exercise
https://jsfiddle.net/crgruyu3/
its work, please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will select 3rd and 6th element in your code.

```
.commitee-members-outers:nth-child(4n+3) .commitee-members{
    margin-left: 83px;
}
```

Comment: waw tq buddy. didnt know this formula save my case

Answer (score 1):

There are 8 children within that element: 3 `.commitee-members-outers`, 1 `.clearfix`, 3 `.commitee-members-outers`, 1 `.clearfix`. All of these elements are counted for the selector.

You could use different tags for the `.clearfix` elements and use `:nth-of-type` to count only the `.commitee-members-outers`.

```
<body>
  <div class="commitee-members-outers"></div>
  <div class="commitee-members-outers"></div>
  <div class="commitee-members-outers"></div>
  <hr class="clearfix" />
  <div class="commitee-members-outers"></div>
  <div class="commitee-members-outers"></div>
  <div class="commitee-members-outers"></div>
  <hr class="clearfix" />
</body>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bheoqL9e/2/)

Comment: i need the div class clearfix for make it 1row event each coloumn have different height. i try with your code <hr class="clearfix"> but its didnt work.

Comment: The fiddle didn't have any css in it. Divs and HRs are both elements that can be styled pretty much the same way: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bheoqL9e/3/)

Comment: Hopefully this showed what the true problem was, anyway :P

Answer (score 0):

Its because `<div class="clearfix"></div>` is interrupting the nth-child property.  Try using other methods to align & fit the divisions.